# Create custom culture without registering it

Tags: .net, localization, cultureinfo

Is it possible to create a custom culture without registering it in Windows? Every solution and documentation refers to [CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.aspx) class with calling `Register` after new culture has been created. But registration of custom culture alters cultures visible in OS and besides it requires admin privileges.

If it's not possible there're two ways to avoid registering a new culture:

1. avoid using custom culture as long as possible, i.e. stick to standard cultures. It can work for now, but I don't know for how long.
2. register custom culture during application install. This is not the option since we can't guarantee admin privileges since we would like to update application remotely.

Are there any ways?

Comment: Did you try [CreateFromLdml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.createfromldml.aspx) that loads a file you [Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder.save.aspx)d earlier and deploy with your app?

Comment: @rene as it mentioned on the MSDN "At this point you could call the Register method and make the reconstituted custom culture available to other applications.". So the recreated cultute must be registered anyway. But we couldn't call a Register method without admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register the custom culture in order to make use of it.

Comment: Yes, but isn't there any other way to use a culture locally, inside my app?

Comment: There isn't, but the places where you may want to use one (number formatting, date formatting), take an IFormatProvider or the specific NumberFormatInfo or DateTimeFormatInfo and you can override those values. Do you have a specific place where you are running into these limitations yet? A specific scenario you want to enable?

Comment: by now I'm OK with standard cultures. But it's possible that I'll have to create custom cultures in future, some specific formatting. Then I'll definitely adopt the idea you've given in your comment - it will be OK to create custom realisation of IFormatProvider for the "special cultures" and pass it where neccessary. Thanks!